# Python: xml.Find always returns none

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So I'm trying to search and replace the xml keyword RunCodeAnalysis inside a vcxproj file with python.
I'm pretty new to python so be gentle, but I thought it would be the simplest language to do this kind of thing.
I read a handful of similar examples and came up with the code below, but no matter what I search for the ElementTree Find call always returns None.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

xml = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Protected_Debug|Win32'">
      <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
'''

et.register_namespace('', "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
tree = et.ElementTree(et.fromstring(xml))
print(tree.find('.//RunCodeAnalysis'))
```

Here's a simplified code example online:  https://ideone.com/1T1wsb

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know why it's happening but 

`>>> tree.find('{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}PropertyGroup')
<Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}PropertyGroup' at 0x7fc1bb8c81d8>`
does work

Comment: Ahh!  thanks @ThomWiggers - so I can use: for item in tree.findall('.//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}RunCodeAnalysis'):
    item.text = 'true'
and that does what I wanted.  Now all I need to do is figure out why it removes the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> part when I use tree.write() and I can get this script working

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. So @ThomWiggers helped me with the missing piece - and here's my final code in all it's naive glory.  No parameter checking or any kind of smarts yet, but it takes two parameters - filename and whether to turn static code analysis to true or false.  I've got about 30 projects I want to turn it on for for nightly builds but really don't want to turn it on day to day as it's just too slow.

```
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

et.register_namespace('', "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
tree = et.parse(sys.argv[1])
value = sys.argv[2]
for item in tree.findall('.//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}RunCodeAnalysis'):
    item.text = value
for item in tree.findall('.//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}EnablePREfast'):
    item.text = value
tree.write(sys.argv[1])
```